# problems when I serialize sparse_hash_map<char *const, int> into file

Tags: c++, serialization

Here is my code to serialize sparse_hash_map(char *const, int) into file, notice the map.key type is `char *const`, which is required(if not, compiler reports no matched function found). That's where problems occurs, since I can't allocate memory to a variable of type `char *const`, how can I read data from serialization file into the map.key before allocating enough memory for it? or, is there any  way to serialize sparse_hash_map(char *const, int) other than this one?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sparsehash/sparse_hash_map>
using google::sparse_hash_map;      // namespace where class lives by default

using namespace std;

#define SIZE 13

struct CharPointerToIntSerializer {
  bool operator()(FILE* fp, std::pair<char * const, int>* value) const {
    // this can't be done, since value->first is of type 'char *const'
    // value->first = realloc(value->first, SIZE);
    if (fread(const_cast<char *>(value->first), 1, SIZE, fp) != 1) {
      return false;
    }

    if (fread(&(value->second), sizeof(value->second), 1, fp) != 1)
      return false;
    return true;
  }

  bool operator()(FILE* fp, const std::pair<char * const, int>& value) const {
    if (fwrite(value.first, 1, SIZE, fp) != 1)
      return false;

    if (fwrite(&value.second, sizeof(value.second), 1, fp) != 1)
      return false;
    return true;
  }
};

int main(){
  sparse_hash_map<char*, int> old_map,new_map;
  char *p1, *p2;
  p1 = (char *) malloc(SIZE);
  p2 = (char *) malloc(SIZE);
  strcpy(p1, "hello");
  strcpy(p2, "world");
  old_map[p1] = 1;
  old_map[p2] = 2;

  FILE* fp = fopen("hashtable.txt", "w");
  old_map.serialize(CharPointerToIntSerializer(), fp);
  // cout << old_map[p1] << endl;
  // cout << old_map[p2] << endl;
  fclose(fp);

  FILE* fp_in = fopen("hashtable.txt", "r");
  new_map.unserialize(CharPointerToIntSerializer(), fp_in);
  fclose(fp_in);
  assert(old_map == new_map);
  cout << new_map[p2] << endl;
}
```

this program compiles, but when i run it, it tells me "segmentation fault 11", and gdb debug results says "memcpy.S: No such file or directory", any help will be appreciated! :)

Comment: Woah woah woah... `char*` as a container key? `strcpy`? `malloc`???? This is C++ and 2015, mate! `std::string`.

Comment: Use `std::string`, life will be a LOT easier this way.

Comment: just curious, can't char* be container key? really that bad?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering the OP's question about char * being really that bad first.

char * massively increases your workload when compared to std::string. First, no need for `malloc` and `free` (you aren't doing the `free` by the way). The sizing and resizing is done for you. In fact, all of the memory management is handled for you unless you are using pointers to std::strings. `strcpy` and all of the overrun checks that go with it becomes `=`. Splitting, searching, and sorting functions are built right in, if you need them. Very handy little guys, std::strings.

As a container key, you likely won't have control of the destruction logic. The pair will be destroyed and the pointer will be destroyed along with it, but the memory pointed to will still be there and need to be `free`d, but you no longer have a pointer with which you can call `free`.

You can `free` the memory before the pair's destructor fires and destroys the pointer, but then you have to guard all of the points in the code where you destroy a pair. Why put up with the headache and tracking code scattered all through your program when it can be done for you?

The problem

```
bool operator()(FILE* fp, std::pair<char * const, int>* value) const {
  // this can't be done, since value->first is of type 'char *const'
  // value->first = realloc(value->first, SIZE);
  if (fread(const_cast<char *>(value->first), 1, SIZE, fp) != 1) {
    return false;
  }

  if (fread(&(value->second), sizeof(value->second), 1, fp) != 1)
    return false;
  return true;
}
```

As you noted, you cannot allocate storage for `value->first` so `fread(const_cast<char *>(value->first), 1, SIZE, fp)` is doomed unless you allocated storage for `value->first` when you first created the pair. If you did not create the pair, odds are really good that `value->first` is pointing to NULL. fread to NULL goes boom.

Next, when that pair is deleted by the map, who `free`s the char*? Probable memory leak.

Problem goes away with string, but you won't want to fread directly into the string.

You'll want something more like

```
  char buf[size+1]; // +1 for null char
  int len = fread(buf, 1, SIZE, fp)
  if (len != 1) {
    return false;
  }
  buf[len] = '0\'; //terminate string with null
  value->first = buf;
```

Buf is allocated on the stack, so it will be destroyed when it passes out of scope, but  by that point it's been copied to the string. You may not need to null buf if it was stored with a guaranteed null.

The error message "memcpy.S: No such file or directory" is GDB trying to display the line that failed and not being able to find the source file containing the memcpy function. The segfault is worth worrying about, the source file being missing, not so important. The bug is somewhere before the call to memcpy. Inspect the stack trace to find your last line of code and start investigating there.